# va_list and char* strings

Tags: c, variadic-functions

**[EDIT]** inserted NULL terminated in samples

I have a function that receives a `va_list` which ends with a `NULL`. I concatenate each string in a `char*` called `joinedString`. Function works as expected except by my `joinedString` grows its size each time I call this function. I mean the previous string remains and new string is joined.

Example:
First call:

```
ShowMsg(style1, "a", "s", "d", NULL);
```

Yielded result: "asd"

Second call:

```
ShowMsg(style1, "w", "w", "q", NULL);
```

Yielded result: "asdwwq"

This behaviour is strange because each time this function is called `joinedString` is initialized. Does va_list holds values previously used?
I'm using C, not C++ and I know, using std::string will be far more easy.

```
int ShowMsg(MSGBOXSTYLE msgStyle, char* str, ...)
{
    char* title = "", *joinedString = "", *theArg = "";
    wchar_t* convertedTitle = "", *convertedString = "";

    va_list args;
    theArg = str;
    va_start( args, str );
        while(theArg != NULL)
        {
            if(msgStyle == WARN)
            {
                title = theArg;
            }
            else
            {
                strcat( joinedString, theArg );
                strcat( joinedString, "\n\r" );
            }
            theArg = va_arg(args, char*);
        }
    va_end(args);
    ...
    convertedTitle = (wchar_t*)malloc((strlen(title)+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
    convertedString = (wchar_t*)malloc((strlen(joinedString)+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
    mbstowcs( convertedTitle, title, strlen(title)+1 );
    mbstowcs( convertedString, joinedString, strlen(joinedString)+1 );
    ...
    free(convertedTitle);
    free(convertedString);
}
```

Comment: "This behaviour is strange because each time this function is called joinedString is initialized" it is always initialized to the pointer to the same string("") and you modify it after, that is not safe. Use malloc to allocate memory for char* vars.

Comment: Your `strcat(joinedString...` looks very suspicious to me.  How much space is assigned to joinedString?  It looks like only one byte to me.

Comment: Another problem : in yours samples you do not terminate the parameter list with a NULL, it should be "ShowMsg(style1, "a", "s", "d", NULL);

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Yes It allocates 1 byte. I did this to try dynamic char* size.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks Mike, added NULL.

Comment: @ShPavel Yes ShPavel. As I said Scott it allocates 1 byte. I did this to try dynamic char* size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you can't initialize strings like that. Your initializer `char* joinedString = ""` is initializing the pointer `joinedString` to point to a specific memory address that at the beginning of your program, consists of an empty string.

Then, the first time you call the function, `joinedString` is set to point to that still empty memory area. You then put some characters there and exit.

Next time you start, the characters are still there. The only thing you initialize is the pointer, not the actual data. `strcat` then appends your new args to the end of the already filled string!

This should be segfaulting, I'm actually pretty impressed that your program is outputting ANYTHING. It's probably only working because you are only using a few bytes, so you're not overwriting too much.

To fix it, initialized joinedString with malloc:

```
char* joinedString = malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(*joinedString));
joinedString[0] = '\0'; // Initialize to an empty string
```

And then at the end of your function, free that memory

```
free(joinedString);
```

Comment: You also need to track the length of joinedString - you'll set a maximum length in the call to `malloc` and then you need to track the maximum length. Use `strncat` to make sure that you never exceed the allocated string length.

Comment: Exactly Dan. My intention with this is to get a variable char*. Isolating this function in a separate program it crashes. Making your suggestions works. But like I said my intention is to get all strings that can be passed and to join them in this char pointer. Because of this I did'nt define a fixed size for char and allocate it. Is this a clean way to do variable char*?

Comment: You must define SOME maximum length, for the sake of simplicity. You MAY dynamically calculate that based on the length of the inputs, but it would require a second loop through your varargs. Simply define a new `int len = 0`, add up the lengths of all the arguments, and add 3 (for the trailing `"\r\n\0"`), then call `malloc` based on that variable. Like I said, you can't do this on the fly, you have to loop through the args to get each length, THEN call `malloc`, THEN loop through the args again to actually `strcpy` them.

Comment: I thought exactly what you said. And I thought too would be possible to avoid another loops. I need to live with this penalty.

Answer (score 3):

`char *joinedString = ""` means joinedString is pointing at a read-only 1-byte character array.

You should not be writing to that section of memory. It will crash on many systems. Also, even if you can, when you write past the end of the array with `strcat( joinedString, theArg );`, you invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: My intention with this is to get a dynamic char*. For me doing this and using strcat char* would be dynamic.

Comment: @learner but it's not dynamic. `char *joinedString = ""` declares `joinedString` as a pointer-to-char, and initializes it to point to a one-byte memory area _that you are not allowed to modify_. Randomly writing into memory that doesn't belong to you isn't dynamic except in the sense of "holding a lit stick of dynamite", maybe.

Comment: If you need a dynamically-resizable block of memory, allocate it with the [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) function, dynamically resize it with the [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html) function, and when you're done, release it with the [`free()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html) function. Remember to check for `malloc()` returning NULL, and remember not to throw away the pointer you're passing to `realloc()` because `realloc()` can also return NULL.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Understood. I forgot `realloc`